# Quadtrees: a common intersect method failing to handle a simple case

Tags: intersection, rectangles, quadtree

I am writing a simple GUI library and am using quadtrees to determine which, if any, objects are interacted with during a mouse event. I was looking through a number of quadtree libraries on github and they all contained a method for adding a rectangular object to a quadtree.
The method, in all cases, simply checked to see if the rectangle intersected with the given quadtree:

```
return quadtree.x2 >= rect.x1
    and quadtree.x1 <= rect.x2
    and quadtree.y2 >= rect.y1
    and quadtree.y1 <= rect.y2
```

However, this gives an unwanted result in one of the simplest cases: Imagine a 100x100 square area. I place four 50x50 square objects into the area with coordinates (0,0), (0,50), (50,0), and (50,50). If these objects had been placed into a 100x100 quadtree with a maximum capacity of one object, I would (visually) expect that the first layer of the quadtree would split and that the four resulting trees would each exactly contain one of the squares.

[image: What should happen]

If I use the above method to determine which tree the squares are placed into, though, I find that each object intersects with all four trees. This would cause each of the trees to rapidly split until the maximum depth is reached.

[image: What does happen]

The only way I see to avoid this is to use two checks:

```
return (quadtree.x2 > rect.x1
    and quadtree.x1 < rect.x2
    and quadtree.y2 > rect.y1
    and quadtree.y1 < rect.y2)
    or (quadtree.x2 == rect.x1
    and quadtree.x1 == rect.x2
    and quadtree.y2 == rect.y1
    and quadtree.y1 == rect.y2)
```

(in the simplest case. Larger objects would have to be viewed within a bounding box since, for example, an object with coordinates (0,0), w=100, h=100 would belong in the upper-left quadtree as well.)

I could also calculate the overlap between the rectangles and the quadtrees to see if it's non-zero.

Am I missing something? It seems like this should be an ideal situation for a quadtree, yet, in most implementations, it's a huge mess.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this an ideal situation, because the four rectangles overlap by a fractional amount. For example, if we assume a (fictional) floating precision of 10^(-10), every 'point' is actually a small rectangle with 10^(-10) length, and thus the rectangles overlap by 10^(-10). This is why you get the deep tree.

But I also think the tree could be improved with a slightly modified overlap checking. With your code, the sub-nodes all overlap by a tiny amount. It would work better with excluding the minimum (or maximum values), for example:

```
return quadtree.x2 >= rect.x1
    and quadtree.x1 < rect.x2
    and quadtree.y2 >= rect.y1
    and quadtree.y1 < rect.y2
```

So the lower left coordinate of a node is actually *outside* of that node. This would at least avoid points turning up in several nodes (such as the point (50,50)), and the lower left rectangle would be stored in only one node.